# Post request with JSON body in Swift

Tags: swift

I have been looking for a similar solution for a long time but I can't find it.

I have to make a post request for my Stripe server.
For that I have to send a request with a JSON in Body : {"price" : 50}.
I can't figure out what's wrong.
Thank you

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    checkoutButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapCheckoutButton), for: .touchUpInside)
      checkoutButton.isEnabled = false
   let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "price": "50",
        ]
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
    var request = URLRequest(url: backendCheckoutUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("\(String(describing: jsonData?.count))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.httpBody = jsonData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
      guard let data = data,
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any],
            let customerId = json["customer"] as? String,
            let customerEphemeralKeySecret = json["ephemeralKey"] as? String,
            let paymentIntentClientSecret = json["paymentIntent"] as? String,
            let publishableKey = json["publishableKey"] as? String,
            let self = self else {
        return
            }
            STPAPIClient.shared.publishableKey = publishableKey

            var configuration = PaymentSheet.Configuration()
            configuration.merchantDisplayName = "Example, Inc."
            configuration.applePay = .init(
                merchantId: "com.foo.example", merchantCountryCode: "US")
            configuration.customer = .init(
                id: customerId, ephemeralKeySecret: customerEphemeralKeySecret)
            configuration.returnURL = "....."
         configuration.allowsDelayedPaymentMethods = true
            self.paymentSheet = PaymentSheet(
                paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentClientSecret,
                configuration: configuration)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.buyButton.isEnabled = true
            }
        })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: What if you do it this way? `let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(parameters)` also, I don't think setting the `Content-Length` header is actually necessary, try removing it.

Comment: Code could be better but seems correct. What's wrong exactly? WHat's happening? Do you have an error? Is `try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data,` failing? What about doing a proper do/try/catch? Is it because the `else { return }` is called in your long `guard let`? If yes, because of which line/test that it's failing? We can't currently guess what's wrong...

Comment: @Larme, @Alejandro thanks, I have this response : 
`(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000022082c0> { URL: http://********} { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5"
    );
    "X-Powered-By" =     (
        Express
    );
} })`

Comment: And `String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)`?

Comment: Thank you Larme, my request is good. Its just I receive a byte in my data. I've create a another topic. Thank you so much